# DOMDocument replace nodeValue text with fragment

Tags: php, html, domdocument

I would like to replace text within a DOMNode with an HTML element fragment.

For example, given this HTML string:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</p>
```

I would like to replace "*dolor sit amet*", wrapping it with an HTML element.

Resulting in something like:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum <em>dolor sit amet</em>, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</p>
```

I am able to append a new fragment to the element with something like the following:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$paragraph = $doc->appendChild($doc->createElement('p', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.'));
$fragment = $doc->createDocumentFragment();
$fragment->appendXML('<em>dolor sit amet</em>');
$paragraph->appendChild($fragment);
```

However, that adds a new element within the paragraph. I can't seem to replace the text within the paragraph with another HTML element, I can only append the element to the end.

I have also tried this approach:

```
$paragraph->nodeValue = str_replace($searchtext, $doc->saveXML($fragment), $paragraph->nodeValue);
```

However, on output that results in an escaped HTML element (`&lt;em&gt;` etc..) in the paragraph value and not a proper HTML element.

Any ideas how to replace the text content or node value with an HTML element?

Thoughts appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, after further testing, I actually found a solution that replaces the text content with a new valid HTML element within DOMDocument.

Sample code as follows:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
// Create sample paragraph element
$paragraph = $doc->appendChild($doc->createElement('p', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.'));
// Create example replacement insert element
$element = $doc->createElement('em', 'dolor sit amet');
// Create element fragment to insert
$fragment = $doc->createDocumentFragment();
// Get new paragraph value
$new_value = str_replace('dolor sit amet', $doc->saveXML($element), $paragraph->nodeValue);
// Add new paragraph value as fragment
$fragment->appendXML('<p>' . $new_value . '</p>');
// Replace paragraph element with new valid fragment
$paragraph->parentNode->replaceChild($fragment, $paragraph);
```

Result:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum <em>dolor sit amet</em>, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</p>
```

Hopefully that helps future readers.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to create a separate element, you can use `preg_replace` function to search for the particular pattern and replace it with your string, like this:

```
$str = "<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</p>";

$doc = new DomDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($str);
$paragraph = $doc->getElementsByTagName('p')->item(0);
$modified_string = preg_replace('/dolor sit amet/', '<em>dolor sit amet</em>', $paragraph->textContent);
echo $modified_string;
```

Output:

[image]

Here's the reference:

- [preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

**Edited:**

```
$str = "<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</p>";

$doc = new DomDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($str);
$paragraph = $doc->getElementsByTagName('p')->item(0);
$paragraph->nodeValue = preg_replace('/dolor sit amet/', '<em>dolor sit amet</em>', $paragraph->textContent);
$str = htmlspecialchars_decode($doc->saveHtml());
echo $str;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, I've tried something similar to that with `str_replace` and setting the `$paragraph->nodeValue` but I found the new element value is not treated as a proper element in the DOMDocument, it's added as escaped HTML. This means it can't be queried by XPath etc.. in the document (which is another requirement). I need to add it as a proper HTML element, replacing the target text to create a valid DOMDocument.

Comment: thanks again, yes that is actually the current solution I'm using, but with `html_entity_decode` on the output. However, it still has the problem that the element is not added as a proper HTML element to the DOMDocument object. It means I can't query the element with xpath inside the document, which is required for replacing more than one nested child element. Nevertheless, upvoted as a reasonable answer, but I'm still looking for a solution that replaces the text with a valid HTML element.

Comment: after further testing, I found the solution I've posted below. Thanks again for your suggestions and wishing you a great 2016 :)

Comment: @DavidThomas Don't forget to mark your answer as *accepted* so that it could be useful for future visitors of SO. Happy new year! :)